# Does Pyparsing Support Context-Sensitive Grammars?

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing, ply

Forgive me if I have the incorrect terminology; perhaps just getting the "right" words to describe what I want is enough for me to find the answer on my own.

I am working on a parser for ODL (Object Description Language), an arcane language that as far as I can tell is now used only by NASA PDS (Planetary Data Systems; it's how NASA makes its data available to the public). Fortunately, PDS is finally moving to XML, but I still have to write software for a mission that fell just before the cutoff.

ODL defines objects in something like the following manner:

```
OBJECT              = TABLE
  ROWS              = 128
  ROW_BYTES         = 512 
END_OBJECT          = TABLE
```

I am attempting to write a parser with `pyparsing`, and I was doing fine right up until I came to the above construction.

I have to create some rule that is able to ensure that the right-hand-value of the OBJECT line is identical to the RHV of END_OBJECT. But I can't seem to put that into a `pyparsing` rule. I can ensure that both are syntactically valid values, but I can't go the extra step and ensure that the values are identical.

1. Am I correct in my intuition that this is a context-sensitive grammar? Is that the phrase I should be using to describe this problem?
2. Whatever kind of grammar this is in the theoretical sense, is `pyparsing` able to handle this kind of construction?
3. If `pyparsing` is not able to handle it, is there another Python tool capable of doing so? How about `ply` (the Python implementation of `lex`/`yacc`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in fact a grammar for a context-sensitive language, classically abstracted as `wcw` where w is in (a|b)* (note that `wcw'` , where `'` indicates reversal, is context-free).

Parsing Expression Grammars are capable of parsing wcw-type languages by using semantic predicates. PyParsing provides the `matchPreviousExpr()` and `matchPreviousLiteral()` helper methods for this very purpose, e.g.

```
w = Word("ab")
s = w + "c" + matchPreviousExpr(w)
```

So in your case you'd probably do something like

```
table_name = Word(alphas, alphanums)
object = Literal("OBJECT") + "=" + table_name + ... +
  Literal("END_OBJECT") + "=" +matchPreviousExpr(table_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, parsers are built as context-free parsing engines.  If there is context sensitivity, it is grafted on after parsing (or at least after the relevant parsing steps are completed).

In your case, you want to write context-free grammar rules:

```
  head = 'OBJECT' '=' IDENTIFIER ;
  tail = 'END_OBJECT'  '=' IDENTIFIER ;
  element = IDENTIFIER '=' value ;
  element_list = element ;
  element_list = element_list element ;
  block = head element_list tail ;
```

The checks that the head and tail constructs have matching identifiers isn't technically done by the parser.

Many parsers, however, allow a semantic action to occur when a syntactic element is recognized, often for the purpose of building tree nodes.  In your case, you want
to use this to enable additional checking.   For *element*, you want to make sure the *IDENTIFIER* isn't a duplicate of something already in the block; this means for each *element* encountered, you'll want to capture the corresponding *IDENTIFIER* and make a block-specific list to enable duplicate checking.  For block, you want to capture the *head* *IDENTIFIER*, and check that it matches the *tail* *IDENTIFIER*.

This is easiest if you build a tree representing the parse as you go along, and hang the various context-sensitive values on the tree in various places (e.g., attach the actual *IDENTIFIER* value to the tree node for the *head* clause). At the point where you are building the tree node for the *tail* construct, it should be straightforward to walk up the tree, find the *head* tree, and then compare the identifiers.

This is easier to think about if you imagine the entire tree being built first, and then a post-processing pass over the tree is used to this checking.  Lazy people in fact do it this way :-}  All we are doing is pushing work that could be done in the post processing step, into the tree-building steps attached to the semantic actions.

None of these concepts is python specific, and the details for PyParsing will vary somewhat.

Comment: In pyparsing, you can attach a parse-time callback (we call it a "parse action") to the expression corresponding to `block`, and it can validate that the `head` and `tail` values agree, or raise a `ParseException`. So you don't have to do a lot of "tree-walking".

Comment: So this is exactly the semantic action I discussed.  Does it build the tree itself? How? If not, how is that you can check the value of the terminals?

Comment: pyparsing passes the parsed structure to the callback, and the callback in this case would look at the first and last elements to compare the object value strings. So I guess there is *some* tree-walking, but only over just the current object that was parsed. And with the addition of some labelling (similar to naming groups in a regular expression), the parse action could look directly at `tokens.head.identifier` and `tokens.tail.identifier` to validate that they match.

Comment: After I posted this question I decided to use the strategy like above. My intuition tells me that since objects are never interleaved, only nested, the simple grammar would parse correctly and I could just assert that the values were the same as an afterthought. But I'm not sure I can prove that. (All the more motivation to go back to school, I suppose.)